# Blackjack Ace functionality python

Tags: python, blackjack

Need help getting the 11 to become 1 when over 21. Anytime a player has 11 and they go over 21 the 11 should convert into a 1? Also if the player decides to hit and is over 11 and the dealt card comes out 11 it should convert to a 1. This is a blackjack game and it should function as one.
```
import random

````
while True:
    cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    card_1 = random.choice(cards)
    card_2 = random.choice(cards)
    card_3 = random.choice(cards)
    card_4 = random.choice(cards)
    player_1 = int(card_1) + int(card_2)
    player_2 = int(card_3) + int(card_4)

    print(f"Your cards: [{card_1}] [{card_2}]\n[{player_1}]")
    print(f"Dealers cards: [{card_3}] [?]")
    if player_1 == 21:
        print("$$$Winner Winner Chicken Dinner$$$")
        while True:
            answer = str(input('Run again? (y/n): '))
            if answer in ('y', 'n'):
                break
            print("invalid input.")
        if answer == 'y':
            continue
        else:
            print("Goodbye")
            break
        
    while player_1 < 21:
        hit_stay = input("Hit[1] or stay[2]? ")
        if hit_stay == "1":
            player_1 += random.choice(cards)
            print("[" + str(player_1) + "]")
            if player_1 <= 21:
                continue
            elif player_1 > 21:
                print("Dealer Wins")
                pass
        elif hit_stay == "2":
            break
    if player_1 > 21:
        while True:
            answer = str(input('Run again? (y/n): '))
            if answer in ('y', 'n'):
                break
            print("invalid input.")
        if answer == 'y':
            continue
        else:
            print("Goodbye")
        break
    print(f"Dealers cards: [{card_3}] [{card_4}]\n[{player_2}]")
    while player_2 <= 16:
        if player_2 > player_1:
            break
        else: 
            player_2 += random.choice(cards) 
            print(f"[{player_2}]")
    if player_2 > 21:
        print("Player Wins")
    elif player_2 > player_1:
        print("Dealer Wins")
    elif player_2 < player_1 and not player_1 > 21:
        print("Player Wins")
    else:
        print("Draw")
    while True:
        answer = str(input('Run again? (y/n): '))
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            break
        print("invalid input.")
    if answer == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print("Goodbye")
    break
    ```
````

Comment: You just answered your question in the description, so what is the problem?

Comment: where and how to code it in?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would want to do is instead of directly adding the card choice to the player or dealer's total, you would want to check the value of their hands if an "Ace" is retrieved.  Following, are the two snippets of code to adjust for those conditions and use a value of "1" instead of "11".

Here would be the change for the player.

```
        while player_1 < 21:
        hit_stay = input("Hit[1] or stay[2]? ")
        if hit_stay == "1":
            amount = random.choice(cards)
            if player_1 > 10 and amount = 11:       # Use a value of "1"
                amount = 1
            player_1 += amount
            print("[" + str(player_1) + "]")
            if player_1 <= 21:
                continue
            elif player_1 > 21:
                print("Dealer Wins")
                pass
        elif hit_stay == "2":
            break
```

Here would be the change for the dealer.

```
        while player_2 <= 16:
        if player_2 > player_1:
            break
        else: 
            amount = random.choice(cards)
            if player_2 > 10 and amount = 11:       # Use a value of "1"
                amount = 1
            player_2 += amount
            print(f"[{player_2}]")
```

That should address your question.  Give that a try.